# "Cannot create infinite type" error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'd like to know why Haskell accepts this

```
perms xs = [ x:y | i <- [0..(length xs - 1)], x <- [xs!!i], y <- perms (takeOut i xs)]
```

but won't accept that:

```
perms xs = [ x:(perms y) | i <- [0..(length xs - 1)], x <- [xs!!i], y <- (takeOut i xs)]
```

It complains that

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( abc.hs, interpreted )

> ```
> Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t = [t]
>   Expected type: t -> [t]
>   Inferred type: [t] -> [[a]]
> In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(perms y)'
> In the expression: x : (perms y)
> ```

I can understand what it says, I just cannot is on why the first one is OK and the second one is not!

EDIT: Ah, of course I also have

```
perms [] = [[]]
```

at the top.

Thanks

Comment: `(x,i) <- zip xs [0..]` instead of `i <- [0..(length xs - 1)], x <- [xs!!i]` is much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a list comprehension, `x <- ys` binds `x` to *each* element in `ys`.  Essentially, you are trying to transform:

```
[ f foo | foo <- bar ]
```

Into

```
[ f bar ]
```

The phrase

```
y <- perms (takeOut i xs)
```

Means "for each permutation `y` of `takeOut i xs`".  So the `[ x:y | ... ]` prepends `x` to each permutation.

Correspondingly, the phrase

```
y <- takeOut i xs
```

Means "for each element `y` of `takeOut i xs`".  So the `[ x:perms y | ... ]` is attempting to find all permutations of the *element* `y` (not even a list), and then prepend `x` to that list of permutations.  The permutations of something is a list of lists, so `x` must be a list to do this, which it is not.  So, basically, the second one makes no sense.

I can see why you would be thrown off.  Just remember, `<-` isn't the same as `let`, it means *for each*.

Answer (score 8):

In the first expression you have `x:y` which means, that if `x :: a` then `y :: [a]`.
In `x : perms y` if `x :: a` then it must be that `perms y :: [a]`, but `perms y :: [[a]]` (list of permutations).
Typechecker tries to unify `[a]` and `[[a]]` and fails.

Comment: This answer is overly technical, and does not give any intuition for the source of the error.

Answer (score 4):

My brain hurts and I'm not an expert, but I think:

In

```
perms xs = [ x:y | i <- [0..(length xs - 1)], x <- [xs!!i], y <- perms (takeOut i xs)]
```

perms (takeOut i  xs) is a list of lists. x is consed onto each element of that list. Perms is invoked on the list as a whole, so perms is a function taking list-of-thing.

In

```
perms xs = [ x:(perms y) | i <- [0..(length xs - 1)], x <- [xs!!i], y <- (takeOut i xs)]
```

(takeOut i xs) is a list, and for each element of that list x is consed onto perms of that element. Perms is invoked on each element of the list, so perms is a function taking thing.

Only the former case is internally consistent, and the typechecker loves you.